# Protect Url from copy and paste in an other browser after loggin in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

I am using the **Google authentication** API in my **Google app engine application** for logging. It is working but, after a user logging, he can copy the URL, sign out and repast the URL he has copped in the browser or in an other browser to open the page without sign in.

**My problem is to prevent that using Google authentication API** if possible or if not, any help will be great thanks.

this is my code to logging

```
<% if (userService.getCurrentUser() == null)
    { %>
        <p><a href="<%= userService.createLoginURL("/home") %>">Se
        connecter</a></p>
    <% }else { %>
        <p>hI <%= userService.getCurrentUser().getNickname() %></p>
        <p><a href="<%= userService.createLogoutURL("/") %>">Se
        déconnecter</a>

  <% } %>
```

please this is part of my web.xml code I have try to use Bruyere solution but I could not adopted my code with those 
Thanks Bruyere But I can still not do it this is an example of my xml code

```
<!-- url for the businesses page. -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Businesses</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>technologyBusiness.BusinessesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Businesses</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/businesses</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- end of the url page. -->
```

so if you can just help me and protect my `<url-pattern>/businesses</url-pattern>`  url will be very  happy. thanks in advance

Comment: you can use the @login_required decorator https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/webapp/utilmodule (for python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using JSP. I would put a [security constraint](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Security_and_Authentication) on any page that you need them to log in. That way if they try and just copy paste it will force them to log in again. Try this right under the "/servlet-mapping"

```
<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>Businesses</web-resource-name>
    <url-pattern>/businesses</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>*</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Comment: Thanks Bruyere but my problem have not been solve please look at the edited code I just post Thans

Comment: Thanks very much I am using JSP now it working but I can't understand how that is redirected me to the home page while i changed it to go to the businesses page please should me show the code ?

Comment: Do you mean why is it asking the user to log in again?